# The line "Add role and company", as it currently appears, is misleading

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Today I edited my profile. After the changes, I checked my profile and noticed a beginning line (with a link) that says

> Add role and company

(see image at the end of the post).

I've spent a few minutes trying to get that line out of my profile. Then I found out that it doesn't show when I'm not logged in, and so it probably doesn't show for other users.

I think it is confusing that this line shows on your profile, *as if it were part of the actual profile text*. Can it be moved somewhere else, out of the profile area? That way it would be clearer that

- only *you* can see that line;
- it is a suggestion for you to edit that information in; and
- it is *not* part of your displayed profile as seen by everyone else.

[image]

Comment: I think that shows up to prospective employers.

Comment: I would expect all the "edit" things to be under the "Edit" tab, it makes more sense for that to be there (IMO).

Comment: @DanLowe Exactly. It's confusing that it appears in the "Profile" tab

Comment: In your specific case, the avatar alone is worth a thousand words.

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone could be confused by this. Why would 'Add role and company' appear on your profile to other users? And how is that link not clear? I doubt many people have been stumped by this...

Comment: @JayIsTooCommon It's confusing _to yourself_, not to others. You see a line in your profile and it takes a while finding out that others don't see it

Comment: @LuisMendo I don't understand why you would think that others could see that option? There's no logical reason as to why it would be publicly viewable, so the assumption that it is, seems a bit odd.

Comment: @JayIsTooCommon Because it appears in the "Profile" tab, not in the "Edit Profile" tab. The "Profile" tab is supposed to show your profile text as seen by everyone, isn't it?

Comment: @LuisMendo I agree it should appear in the 'Edit Profile' tab, I just struggle to understand how it could be seen as confusing or misleading. +1 for moving it, -1 for it actually being an issue, I guess.

Comment: @JayIsTooCommon It's confusing because it breaks the semantics of the "Profile" tab. Now it doesn't mean "this is the profile text as seen by everyone". So what does it mean?

Comment: @LuisMendo Where does it say "this is the profile text as seen by everyone"? Once you see the option you're discussing, I think it's clear that it's a mixture of both imo. Anyway, +1 for moving it.

Comment: @JayIsTooCommon _mixture_ <-> _confusion_ :-)

Comment: @JayIsTooCommon: It's a reasonably common idiom when separating "view" from "edit", that "edit" widgets are only shown on the "edit" page and the "view" page is your actual profile, largely true to life (modulo maybe some permissions discrepancies). Mixing the two is obviously confusing!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition You keep chainging your name. Luckily your avatars and your rep are recognizable :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo: It shouldn't be relevant, as you should judge content on its own merits rather than on its author. :)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Not relevant, of course. But one gets a habit of trying to "recognize" people here :-)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Yeah, that's a fair point.

Comment: That pattern of advertising things you can change for "completing" your data inside a view panel is not uncommon. So I am surprised it could be deemed confusing. Now I dislike that pattern. Once I have decided to not provide some data, I do not want to be advertised about it constantly. In my opinion, this kind of pattern should have a "dismiss" option allowing to no more see it.

Comment: And use a different font or color, to give a visual clue that the line you are  seeing _in_ your profile is not part of your profile